# Snake plant new growth

Tags: snake-plants

Why is the new growth on my snake plant losing color. I have one in garden soil and the other in potting mix. The older leaves color remain vibrant but the new leaves are not.

[image]

They are on my balcony where they receive indirect sunlight.

Answer (score 1):

The new leaves start off with a slightly lighter color, but when mature it will have the same color as the older leaves. They need to adjust first, that is completely normal.